# SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 2004 3rd Edition Converter

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I'm looking for a free SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 2004 3rd edition converter.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the content is already talking directly to the LMS.
SCORM 1.2 you'll have say lms.LMSGetValue(n) vs SCORM 2004 you'll have lms.GetValue(n).
So you could look for 'API_1484_11' instead of 'API', then make the translations like above and that could solve the problem.  Far as I know though there is no magic converter.

http://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot.
Wiki is updated.  I built it to talk SCORM 2004 but roll back to 1.2 semi gracefully but, with some level of understanding about the character limits and the fact most of 1.2 was optionally implemented on a LMS.  At minimum some stuff to draw off of.

Depending on the "API" look-up mechanism in SCORM 1.2, you may be able to spoof it.  Essentially let the content connect to a fake "API" and then forward to the API_1484_11.  Depends if the look-up starts from the top down or the bottom up though.

Good luck